# Game programming - keep player within playing field & avoiding certain obstacles

Tags: java

My class is learning about Java subclassing and `extends` next week. Our lecturer gave us this code for a game where the AI moved around and collects so called "apples".

`A` is the good apple while `B` is the bad apple. The `1`s moving around (when the code is run) is our player. The player automatically moves towards apple `A` regardless of whether apple `B` is within its range or not. It also tends to travel out of bounds, which will stop the program. If the player doesn't go out of bounds, then the program will stop once it's looped 500 times.

Our lecturer has asked us to correct a certain part in this code so that

1. The player AI never goes out of bounds and,
2. The player AI avoids apple `B` whenever possible (unless its near the border then the player will have no choice but to take the bad apple)

The only places we're allowed to correct are marked with `※1` (`class MyPlayerAI extends PlayerAIBase`) and `※2` (`PlayerAIBase playerAI = new in main class`). I've been trying to add conditions and what not but still I can't seem to get the desired outcome.

I know this question may be vague and open-ended, but can someone please help me as to what I should correct in this code? Any help/pointers is extremely appreciated. I'm not asking straight for a solution, but I'm just very lost at this point.

I've also added a link at the very end to my repl to run this code.

```
import java.util.*;

class GameObject {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    char mark = '*';

    public GameObject(double x, double y, char mark) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.mark = mark;
    }
}

class GoodApple extends GameObject {
    public GoodApple(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y, 'A');
    }
    public GoodApple(GoodApple other) {
        super(other.x, other.y, other.mark);
    }
}

class BadApple extends GameObject {
    public BadApple(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y, 'B');
    }
    public BadApple(BadApple other) {
        super(other.x, other.y, other.mark);
    }
}

class Player extends GameObject {
    public double vx;
    public double vy;

    public Player(double x, double y, char mark) {
        super(x, y, mark);
        vx = 0.0;
        vy = 0.0;
    }
    public Player(Player other) {
        super(other.x, other.y, other.mark);
        this.vx = other.vx;
        this.vy = other.vy;
    }
}

class Accel {
    double ax;
    double ay;
    public Accel(double ax, double ay) {
        this.ax = ax;
        this.ay = ay;
    }
}

class PlayerAIBase {
    public Accel next(Player player, GoodApple goodApple, BadApple badApple, double stageSize) {
        return new Accel(0.0, 0.0);
    }
}

class PlayerAIDummyHead extends PlayerAIBase {
    @Override
    public Accel next(Player player, GoodApple goodApple, BadApple badApple, double stageSize) {
        double dx = goodApple.x - player.x;
        double dy = goodApple.y - player.y;
        Accel a = new Accel(dx / 4, dy / 4);
        return a;
    }
}

class MyPlayerAI extends PlayerAIBase {
    // ※1 recode class PlayerAIDummyHead so that player does not go out of bounds, and avoids apple B

  // public Accel next(Player player, GoodApple goodApple, BadApple badApple, double stageSize) {

  //   }

}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PlayerAIBase playerAI = new PlayerAIDummyHead(); // ※2 change this line to PlayerAIBase playerAI = new MyPlayerAI(); 

        GameManager gm = new GameManager(playerAI);

        gm.initializeStage();
        while (gm.gameTick < 500) {
            gm.printStage();
            System.out.println("time: " + gm.gameTick + " score: " + gm.playerScore);
            Thread.sleep(50);
            gm.next();
            if (gm.playerDropped) {
                break; // while gm.gameTick
            }
        }
        gm.printStage();
        System.out.println("time: " + gm.gameTick + " score: " + gm.playerScore);
    }
}

class GameManager {
    static final double stageSize = 20.0;
    static final double maxAccel = 1.0;
    static final double maxVelocity = 2.5;

    Random rand = new Random();

    PlayerAIBase playerAI;
    int playerScore;
    int gameTick;
    Player player;
    boolean playerDropped;
    GoodApple goodApple;
    BadApple badApple;

    public GameManager(PlayerAIBase playerAI) {
        this.playerAI = playerAI;
    }

    public void initializeStage() {
        playerScore = 0;
        gameTick = 0;
        double r = stageSize - 2.0 * 2;
        player = new Player(rand.nextDouble() * r + 2.0, rand.nextDouble() *  r + 2.0, '1');
        goodApple = new GoodApple(rand.nextDouble() * r + 2.0, rand.nextDouble() *  r + 2.0);
        badApple = new BadApple(rand.nextDouble() * r + 2.0, rand.nextDouble() *  r + 2.0);
    }

    public static double distance(GameObject obj, double px, double py) {
        double dx = obj.x - px;
        double dy = obj.y - py;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public static double distance(GameObject obj1, GameObject obj2) {
        double dx = obj1.x - obj2.x;
        double dy = obj1.y - obj2.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public void printStage() {
        int stageDisplaySize = 20;
        int stageDisplayMarginSize = 2;
        GameObject[] objs = { player, badApple, goodApple };
        for (int y = 0; y < stageDisplaySize + 2 * stageDisplayMarginSize; ++y) {
            double py = (y - stageDisplayMarginSize) * stageSize / stageDisplaySize;
            for (int x = 0; x < stageDisplaySize + 2 * stageDisplayMarginSize; ++x) {
                double px = (x - stageDisplayMarginSize) * stageSize / stageDisplaySize;
                boolean printed = false;
                for (GameObject obj : objs) {
                    if (distance(obj, px, py) <= 1.0) {
                        System.out.print(obj.mark);
                        printed = true;
                        break;  // for obj
                    }
                }
                if (! printed) {
                    if (0.0 <= py && py <= stageSize && 0.0 <= px && px <= stageSize) {
                        System.out.print('.');
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(' ');
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void next() {
        ++gameTick;

        Accel playerAccel = playerAI.next(new Player(player), new GoodApple(goodApple), new BadApple(badApple), stageSize);
        // if the absolute acceleration is more than maxAccel, recalculate to keep within bounds of maxAccel
        double aSize = Math.sqrt(playerAccel.ax * playerAccel.ax + playerAccel.ay * playerAccel.ay);
        if (aSize > maxAccel) {
            playerAccel.ax = playerAccel.ax / aSize * maxAccel;
            playerAccel.ay = playerAccel.ay / aSize * maxAccel;
        }

        player.vx += playerAccel.ax;
        player.vy += playerAccel.ay;
        // if absolute value of speed is more than maxVelocity, recalculate to keep within bounds of maxVelocity
        double vSize = Math.sqrt(player.vx * player.vx + player.vy * player.vy);
        if (vSize > maxVelocity) {
            player.vx = player.vx / vSize * maxVelocity;
            player.vy = player.vy / vSize * maxVelocity;
        }

        int timeResolution = 8;
        for (int t = 0; t < timeResolution; ++t) {
            player.x += player.vx / timeResolution;
            player.y += player.vy / timeResolution;
            if (player.x < 0.0 || player.x >= stageSize || player.y < 0.0 || player.y >= stageSize) {
                playerDropped = true;
                break; // for t
            }

            if (badApple != null && distance(player, badApple) < 2.0) {
                playerScore -= 10;
                badApple = null;
            }

            if (goodApple != null && distance(player, goodApple) < 2.0) {
                playerScore += 1;
                goodApple = null;
            }
        }

        if (badApple == null) {
            double r = stageSize - 2.0 * 2;
            badApple = new BadApple(rand.nextDouble() * r + 2.0, rand.nextDouble() *  r + 2.0);
        }
        if (goodApple == null) {
            double r = stageSize - 2.0 * 2;
            goodApple = new GoodApple(rand.nextDouble() * r + 2.0, rand.nextDouble() *  r + 2.0);
        }
    }
}
```

[Good Apple vs Bad Apple](https://repl.it/@s185050/JAVATestRun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're given is well-written, so first go over it and try to understand what each class and method do even if you don't understand how they do what they do.

> can someone please help me as to what I should correct in this code?

The instructions on what you're supposed to correct and where are also clear:

- ※1 is where you need to implement the new player AI logic such that it conforms to the behavior you were given.
- ※2 is just a simple replacement of the old player AI logic implementing class `PlayerAIDummyHead` with the new one you wrote in ※1, `MyPlayerAI`. It's explicitly given to you in the comment on that line.

To solve ※1, first understand what the current behavior is. `PlayerAIDummyHead` accelerates the player by an amount, and in a direction, which is dependent to the current distance between it and `A`. This calculation is done in a loop, so the acceleration changes on every iteration according to the result the previous acceleration gave.

This movement behavior is problematic in the sense that it does not take into account the location of `B` or the size of the stage, both of which are given the the computing method. In your `MyPlayerAI`'s `next` method, try to improve the math bit by bit to make a more desirable path towards `A`. That's your main task: improve the math that calculates the route.

> Any help/pointers is extremely appreciated.

Just a few ideas you can play around with:

- Make the player take a direct route towards `A`.
- Aim for having 0 velocity when you reach `A`. This will avoid going out of stage when you can't stop in time to reverse direction.
- See if `B` lies in the path of that direct route. If so, move sideways or diagonally until it's not in that path.
- Avoid going out of bounds when maneuvering.

> I understand that the acceleration changes on every iteration but I can't really make out how it's used to calculate the next step the player is supposed to take.

The acceleration changes the velocity (speed):

```
player.vx += playerAccel.ax;
player.vy += playerAccel.ay;
```

Then the velocity changes the position by executing

```
player.x += player.vx / timeResolution;
player.y += player.vy / timeResolution;
```

`timeResolution` times, so it's basically `player.x += player.vx` (same for `y`).

So the acceleration determines how the velocity changes, which determines how the position changes. If you want to reach a point, it's enough to accelerate towards it once (will set a positive velocity in that direction), then set the acceleration to 0 (will keep the constant velocity), then set a negative acceleration once (will lower the velocity, possibly to 0). If you want to get to that point faster, keep a positive acceleration which will make the velocity grow even more, but remember to decelerate in time to lower this large velocity.

Comment: First off, thanks a lot for your very kind answer!
I've gone through all the classes and just about understood what each class/method is doing. 
However, I can't really understand the calculations they're doing. I've tried to use System.out.println(); to see what the numbers used in the calculations are, but I think that's only made me more confused...
I understand that the acceleration changes on every iteration but I can't really make out how its used to calculate the next step the player is supposed to take. 
May I ask for some pointers on this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Joel See my edit to the pointers and the answer to your comment.